# Two navigation and one logo in header

Tags: html, css

I have a problem, I need to do, two navigation and one logo on left side. What I need you can see on image below

I need to do effectively and responsively, when the browser shrinks, gaps will gradually shrink until it jumps to the hamburger menu.

Below you see how I have it now, the picture I need but I do not know how to do it

[image]

```css
.site-nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
}
.site-nav .nav-logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
}
.site-nav .nav-logo img {
  width: 97px;
  height: 47px;
  margin: auto 0;
}
.site-nav .nav-links {
  height: 100px;
  float: right;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.site-nav .nav-links ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
}
.site-nav .nav-links ul li {
  float: left;
  margin: auto;
  padding-left: 16px;
}
.site-nav .nav-links ul li:not(:last-child) {
  padding-right: 16px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="site-nav">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="nav-logo">
                <img src="logo.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="nav-links">
                <ul class="nav-list">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: .site-nav { justify-content: space-evenly;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested flexboxes and media queries to get the desired result. I used dummy images for the logo and the hamburger.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.site-nav {
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav-links {
  display: none;
}

.nav-links .nav-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
}

.mobile-menu {
  position: relative;
}

.mobile-menu .nav-list {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -90px;
  left: -40px;
}

.mobile-menu:hover>.nav-list {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-links .nav-list>li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .mobile-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-links {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="site-nav">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="nav-logo">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="mobile-menu">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/30x30" alt="">
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-links">
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-links">
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Ouu, this is exactly what I wanted. Is not it bad that there is more navigation and another is used for mobile?

Comment: It is either this, or having the menu defined once and add a lot of complexity to the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following example. With css [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) it's easy to specify columns. With extra properties like `justify-content` you can specify how the columns are spaced.

```css
.site-nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.site-nav .container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr 1fr;
}

.site-nav .nav-logo {
  grid-column: 1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
}
.site-nav .nav-logo img {
  width: 97px;
  height: 47px;
  margin: auto 0;
}

.site-nav .nav-links {
 grid-column: auto;
}

.site-nav {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.site-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="site-nav">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="nav-logo">
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/08/19/19/56/peacock-feathers-3617474_960_720.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="nav-links">
                <ul class="nav-list">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            
            <div class="nav-links">
                <ul class="nav-list">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```